# How to add more attributes to product collection

Tags: attributes, collection, product-attribute, product-collection

It seems that many of the custom attributes that i've created aren't present in the product collection that i'm producing.  How do I add more of them?  This is the method I use to get the new product collection.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    $todayStartOfDayDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
        ->setTime('00:00:00')
        ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    $todayEndOfDayDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
        ->setTime('23:59:59')
        ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    //$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or' => array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or' => array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
            )
        )
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1);
    return $collection;
}
```

The resultant __tostring() of the collection looks like this:

> SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`,
>   `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS
>   `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`,
>   `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`,
>   IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price,
>   price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
>   `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`,
>   `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`,
>   `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`,
>   `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`,
>   `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`,
>   `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`,
>   `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`,
>   `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`,
>   `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`,
>   `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`,
>   `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`giftcard_amounts`, `e`.`allow_open_amount`,
>   `e`.`open_amount_min`, `e`.`open_amount_max`, `e`.`entity_id`,
>   `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`allow_open_amount`,
>   `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`email_template`,
>   `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`giftcard_amounts`,
>   `e`.`giftcard_type`, `e`.`gift_message_available`,
>   `e`.`gift_wrapping_available`, `e`.`gift_wrapping_price`,
>   `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`,
>   `e`.`is_redeemable`, `e`.`lifetime`, `e`.`links_exist`,
>   `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`,
>   `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`,
>   `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`open_amount_max`,
>   `e`.`open_amount_min`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`,
>   `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`,
>   `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`,
>   `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`,
>   `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`,
>   `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`,
>   `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`,
>   `e`.`use_config_email_template`, `e`.`use_config_is_redeemable`,
>   `e`.`use_config_lifetime`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`,
>   `e`.`weight_type` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON
>   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND
>   cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'  INNER
>   JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
>   price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1'
>   AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (((((e.news_from_date <=
>   '2015-02-04 23:59:59') OR (e.news_from_date IS null))))) AND
>   (((((e.news_to_date >= '2015-02-04 00:00:00') OR (e.news_to_date IS
>   null))))) AND ((`e`.`news_from_date` IS not null) OR
>   (`e`.`news_to_date` IS not null))

Comment: wat you have tried till now can you show ?

Comment: please show your code.////

Comment: added the method i'm using to get new product collection.

Comment: try ->addAttributeToSelect('*') before ->addStoreFilter()

Comment: @PradeepSanku I ran the resultant $collection->getSelect()->__toString() in our sql program and the query doesn't include things like 'brand' or 'product type' which is located in the meta information of the product's admin section.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here.

1. Use `->addAttributeToSelect(array('attr1', 'attr2', ...))`. This should make your attributes be loaded in the collection and you have control on what you load.
2. You can edit the attributes you want in the list and set the flag `use in product list` to `yes`. Then rebuild the indexes. This is fast and requires no coding. the downside is the attributes will be loaded in every product list and might impact performance.